How to Trigger a Destruction Animation on a Character When a Bomb Explodes in GameMaker Studio?
I'm developing a Mario Bros clone using GameMaker Studio, and I've added a unique feature where Mario can throw bombs to defeat enemies. While I've successfully implemented the bomb-throwing mechanics, I'm encountering difficulties with the animation and interaction side—specifically, how to trigger a destruction animation on enemies when they are hit by an explosion.
The scenario is straightforward: Mario throws a bomb, the bomb has a timer, and upon reaching zero, it explodes. Any enemy within the blast radius should play a destruction animation and then be removed from the game. I have the animations ready but need guidance on how to detect collision between the bomb's explosion and the enemies, and how to play the destruction animation for the affected enemies.
Could anyone provide insights or point me towards the right functions or methods in GameMaker Studio to detect the explosion's impact on enemies and trigger the appropriate animation? Any help with the logic or code snippets to make this work would be incredibly helpful.
So far, I've implemented the bomb-throwing mechanics where Mario can throw a bomb that explodes after a set time. I've used an alarm in GameMaker Studio to manage the countdown for the bomb explosion. Upon explosion, I attempted to check for collision with enemies using the instance_place function in an Area of Effect (AoE) around the bomb. Here's a simplified version of the code I used in the bomb's alarm[0] event for the explosion:
// Explosion effect
instance_create_layer(x, y, "Effects", obj_Explosion);

// Check for enemies in the explosion radius
var _explosionRadius = 64;
var _enemy = instance_place(x, y, obj_Enemy);

if (_enemy != noone && point_distance(x, y, _enemy.x, _enemy.y) <= _explosionRadius) {
    // Intended to trigger the destruction animation for the enemy
    with (_enemy) {
        sprite_index = spr_enemy_destroyed;
        image_index = 0;
        alarm[1] = room_speed * 0.5; // Attempt to remove the enemy after 0.5 seconds
    }
}


I was expecting that when a bomb explodes, any enemy within a 64-pixel radius would immediately start playing their destruction animation (spr_enemy_destroyed) and then be removed from the game after a short delay. However, the animation isn't triggering as expected, and enemies sometimes don't react to the explosion if they're on the edge of the radius. Additionally, enemies are not being removed consistently, indicating a flaw in my approach or understanding.
I'm looking for guidance on how to properly detect all enemies within the explosion radius and ensure the destruction animation plays reliably before removing them from the game. Is there a more efficient way to handle this in GameMaker Studio, or am I missing a crucial step in the collision detection and animation triggering process?
`

I think everything underneath the // Check for enemies in the explosion radius fits better in the Step Event of the obj_Explosion than the Alarm of your Bomb effect.
This is because the Alarm will only be visited once when triggered, so enemies will only react to it if it was in range of the initial moment the explosion triggered.
instance_place will only work for one object, so if multiple enemies will get caught in the explosion they won't register. It also looks like you're checking twice if the enemy is in range of the explosion. (with both instance_place and point_distance) An alternate option is to make the enemy only react to the Collission Event of the explosion.
As for your enemy destroy. There exists a Destroy Event, and that will trigger when the object is about to get removed from the game. This Event is ideal to place explosion effects for the enemy. You can also use it to make an effect appear while the enemy is already removed. (for example, your spr_enemy_destroyed could also be an effect that lasts 0,5 seconds), and removing the enemy before the effect ends, means that it won't interact with the player or other objects in a negative way.
So, summarized:
You can keep this line in your obj_bomb Alarm, but remove the rest
instance_create_layer(x, y, "Effects", obj_Explosion);

Put this in your obj_Explosion Collision Event with obj_Enemy (you may want to adjust the collision mask of the explosion:
with (other) {
    sprite_index = spr_enemy_destroyed;
    image_index = 0;
    alarm[1] = room_speed * 0.5; // Attempt to remove the enemy after 0.5 seconds
}

Or make the enemy destroy sprite an effect, and trigger the effect in the Destroy Event, leaving only this in the Collision Event:
instance_destroy(other)

